# Ошибка при отправлении текстового файла ботом telegram

Tags: python-3.x, telegram-bot, telegram

Не могу понять как заставить бота отправлять текстовые файлы.

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("TOKEN")
doc = open('test.txt', 'rb')
bot.send_document(chat_id, doc)
```

Ошибка:

```
send_document() takes 1 positional argument but 3 were given
```

Answer (score 0):

Проверь какую библиотеку используешь. В репозитории есть именно `telebot`. Её можно случайно установить из pycharm. Тебе скорее всего надо `pyTelegramBotAPI`. Вот ссылка на [библиотеку](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI).